# jQuery clone() function weird behaviour within plugin

Tags: jquery

I encountered a weird problem with the `clone()` function in jQuery and I can't figure out what causes it.

I'm am trying to create a slider jQuery plugin, in this plugin I clone the first slider element and append it to the slider-container.
This all works great when there is only one slider on the page.
But when there are two sliders on the page, the `clone()` function seems to append the cloned element to both sliders.
Resulting in every slider have two extra elements with a class `cloned` instead of just one.

I'm wrapping my plugin code within the  `this.each(function() {...}`.
Next, I define the slider variable from `$(this)` and with every jQuery select within my plugin I pass the context as the second parameter: `$('.slider-item', slider)`.
To my knowledge that should be find and should only append the cloned element to the `slider-container` with the `slider` (thus `$(this)`) context.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a link to a codepen: http://codepen.io/Bogardo/pen/zdnuK

And here is the code for the people that don't like codepen:

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slider-container">
      <li class="slider-item">1</li>
      <li class="slider-item">2</li>
      <li class="slider-item">3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slider-container">
      <li class="slider-item">1</li>
      <li class="slider-item">2</li>
      <li class="slider-item">3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.slider').slider();
</script>
```

Here is a stripped down version of my plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.slider = function() {

        this.each(function() {  

            var slider = $(this),
            items = $('.slider-item', slider);

            items.first()
                .clone()
                .appendTo('.slider-container', slider)
                .addClass('clone');
        });  

        return this;  
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that appendTo supports syntax with multiple arguments?

Maybe, you should try this:

```
.appendTo(slider.find('.slider-container'))
```

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I did not try that. It actually works... Big thanks!